# Best way to use downloaded image in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android

What is the best approach to use downloaded image as photo in Navigation Drawer (or any other layout)?

[image: NavDrawer Example]

To be more specific I'll tell the whole idea - I have 2 Activities, first of them give user opportunity to login with usage of 3d part SDK, if login was successful app receive JSON Obj with user name and url of his avatar, then second Activity is shown, where user could call Navigation Drawer. So I need to download photo with the provided url and show it in the Nav Drawer.

For downloading I'm currently using Picasso:

```java
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(URL).into(target);
```

Than I'm loading this image into the view in the RecyclerViewAdapter like this:

```
Picasso.with(cntx).load(new File(cntx.getFilesDir() + "/photo.png")).into(imgView);
```

But I'm not sure that I'm doing all this stuff in the right way and there are exist some other more rigth approach.

Comment: Since for the 2nd time you use cached image then I do not see much problem with this approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first step is unnecessary. You don't need to download to a file. Picasso already caches to disk when it can, so in your RecyclerViewAdapter, if you load the image via Picasso it will pick memory cache first, and if it's not available, then disk cache, and then if it's not available it will request it from the remote URL. It's all very seamless and quick.